# How to vertical select text in BeyondCompare text editor?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

Visual Studio 2019/2022 text editor supports vertical selection using Alt+mouse_drag but I cant seem to figure out if BeyondCompare supports this in its editor or not.

Need to edit a bunch of lines to fix indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond Compare doesn't support vertical selection. It's on the feature request list for a future version but doesn't have a scheduled release date.

Search and replace is a possible workaround.

Example: To change two spaces of leading indentation to four spaces.

1. Load a file in the Text Compare.
2. **Search > Replace**.
3. Click the .* button to enable regular expressions.
4. Find what: `^`   (carat followed by two spaces).
5. Replace with:      (four spaces).

Beyond Compare also provides commands to convert whitespace:

- Edit > Convert File > Trim Trailing Whitespace.
- Edit > Convert File > Leading Spaces to Tabs.
- Edit > Convert File > Tabs to Spaces.